# Realm and RecyclerView Item sorting and automatic ViewPager Fragment Communication

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview, realm

I'm facing a few problems for a while now which I'm having trouble to solve. So I refer to the Realm and RecyclerView geniuses among the community.
I'm woking on a ToDo-List that sets completed tasks back to the ToDo-List after 2 days. The app uses a ViewPager with two tabs: "TODO" & "DONE".

**1. RecyclerView**

1.1. I want the completed Tasks from fragment 1 to be sent back to fragment 0 automatically after 2 days.
The Problem: If the counter is at 0 (or below) the item gets sent to fragment 0.
If I delte the item in the next line I get an exception error: `"java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling"`
So I put the delete function into a handler. Then it's working BUT only if ONE gets sent back. If many items get sent back simultaneously the app crashes. When I reopen the app everything is working because it was successfully saved in realm but one item is always saved twice.
Where's the Problem (in DoneAdapter.java)?

**2. Realm**

2.1. When I add an Item to the RecyclerView (and simultaneously to Realm), the item gets added at the bottom. But I want to add every new item at position 0. 
(I know how to achieve this wih an ArrayList, but I want the items to be stored and displayed when I reopen the app, so I'm using Realm DB.) 
Do you have any suggestions to achieve this?

2.2. Is it possible to implement later on the onLongClickListener for dragging and droping items and rearranging the position with Realm? 
(I want to use this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tNgevYpyA9E)

2.3. I want to add some nice animations when I add and check an item. Realm doesn't support `mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(...);` but I heard it is possible by adding `mAdapter.setHasStableIds(true);`. Unfortunately it throws an Exception: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot change whether this adapter has stable IDs while the adapter has registered observers.` (You can see this in my code below)
Do you have any solutions for that?

(optionally 1.4. Can you recommend me any Online DBs (e.g. Firebase) which I can sync with Realm or more generally: is it possible to sync an Online DB with Realm? Do you know any Tutorials (Udemy, YouTube) for setting up this sync process?)

Lastly: I want to update the Database with a background service every Midnight, so the counter in the completed section updates automatically. Does anyone know how to do this as well? Maybe with `protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)`? 
Do you also know if there's an option in debugging mode to simulate passing time?

Here is the code:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ToOtherFragmentCommunicator {


private ViewPagerAdapter mViewPagerAdapter;
private ViewPager mViewPager;
private static final int DONE = 1;
private static final int TODO = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    mViewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mViewPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });

    RealmConfiguration configuration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this).build();
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(configuration);
}

@Override
public void itemToOtherFragment(String data, int fragment) {
    if (DONE == fragment) {
        Done done = (Done) mViewPagerAdapter.getItem(fragment);
        done.createDoneItem(data);
    } else if (TODO == fragment) {
        ToDo toDo = (ToDo) mViewPagerAdapter.getItem(fragment);
        toDo.createToDoItem(data);
    }
}
}
```

ToDo.java

```
public class ToDo extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private ToDoAdapter mAdapter;
private EditText taskInput;
private String taskName;
private Realm mRealm;
private RealmResults<ListItems> mResults;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View toDoView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.todo_layout, container, false);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) toDoView.findViewById(R.id.todo_rv);


    mRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    mResults = mRealm.where(ListItems.class).equalTo("fragment", 0).findAllAsync();

    setRecyclerView();

    mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(null);

    //TODO add product to shopping list
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    taskInput = (EditText) toDoView.findViewById(R.id.task_input);
    taskInput.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (taskInput.getText().length() > 0 && (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
                    (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                // Perform action on key press
                taskName = taskInput.getText().toString();

                //Problem 2.1
                //Code for adding item at the top with mRealm?
                mRealm.beginTransaction();
                createToDoItem(taskName);
                mRealm.commitTransaction();


//                    mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);
                taskInput.setText(null);

                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        taskInput.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                        taskInput.setFocusable(true);
                        taskInput.requestFocus();
                    }
                }, 200);

                return true;

            } else if (taskInput.length() == 0 && (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
                    (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                taskInput.clearFocus();
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(taskInput.getWindowToken(), 0);
                return true;
            }

            return false;

        }
    });

    return toDoView;
}


//TODO creates the shopping list item in DB
public void createToDoItem(String taskName) {

    ListItems item = mRealm.createObject(ListItems.class);

    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    item.setAddedTime(now);
    item.setFragment(0);

    item.setTaskName(taskName);

    mRealm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(item);
}

public void setRecyclerView() {
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mAdapter = new ToDoAdapter(getActivity(), mRealm, mResults);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    //Problem 2.3.
    //Produces "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot change whether this adapter has stable IDs while the adapter has registered observers."
//        mAdapter.setHasStableIds(true);
}

private RealmChangeListener mChangeListener = new RealmChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChange() {
        mAdapter.updateItems(mResults);
    }
};

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mResults.addChangeListener(mChangeListener);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mResults.removeChangeListener(mChangeListener);
}


}
```

ToDoAdapter.java

```
public class ToDoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListItemsViewHolder> {

private Context mContext;
private Realm mRealm;
private RealmResults<ListItems> mResults;
private int focusedItem = 0;
ToOtherFragmentCommunicator comm;

ToDoAdapter(Context context, Realm realm, RealmResults<ListItems> mResults) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mRealm = realm;
    updateItems(mResults);
}

public void updateItems(RealmResults<ListItems> mResults) {
    this.mResults = mResults;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

//Problem 2.3.
//needed for mAdapter.setHasStableIds(true); in ToDo.java
//    @Override
//    public long getItemId(int position) {
//        if (position < mResults.size()) {
//            return mResults.get(position).getAddedTime();
//        } else {
//            return RecyclerView.NO_ID;
//        }
//    }

@Override
public ListItemsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.todo_item, parent, false);
    comm = (ToOtherFragmentCommunicator) mContext;
    return new ListItemsViewHolder(v);

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ListItemsViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final ListItems items = mResults.get(position);


    holder.taskName.setText(items.getTaskName());

    holder.itemView.setSelected(focusedItem == position);
    holder.getLayoutPosition();

    holder.itemCheckbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
    holder.itemCheckbox.setChecked(items.isSelected());

    holder.itemCheckbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            mRealm.beginTransaction();
            items.setSelected(isChecked);

            //send item to Done
            comm.itemToOtherFragment(items.getTaskName(), 1);

            removeItem(position);
            mRealm.commitTransaction();

        }
    });


}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (mResults != null ? mResults.size() : 0);
}

private void removeItem(int position) {
    mResults.get(position).removeFromRealm();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

}
```

Done.java

```
public class Done extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private DoneAdapter mAdapter;
private Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
private Date date = new Date();
private SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
private Realm mRealm;
private RealmResults<ListItems> mResults;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View doneView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.done_layout, container, false);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) doneView.findViewById(R.id.done_rv);

    mRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    mResults = mRealm.where(ListItems.class).equalTo("fragment", 1).findAllAsync();

    setRecyclerView();
    mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(null);


    return doneView;
}


//TODO creates the fridge item in DB
public void createDoneItem(String taskName) {
    TimeZone.getDefault();


    ListItems item = mRealm.createObject(ListItems.class);

    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    item.setAddedTime(now);
    item.setFragment(1);

    item.setTaskName(taskName);
    item.setInputDate(simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));

    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 2);
    item.setRenewDate(simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));


    //reset time to current date after adding days
    calendar.setTime(date);

    item.getRenewDate();

    mRealm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(item);
}


public void setRecyclerView() {
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mAdapter = new DoneAdapter(getActivity(), mRealm, mResults, Done.this);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}


private RealmChangeListener mChangeListener = new RealmChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChange() {
        mAdapter.updateItems(mResults);
    }
};

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mResults.addChangeListener(mChangeListener);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mResults.removeChangeListener(mChangeListener);
}
}
```

DoneAdapter.java

```
public class DoneAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListItemsViewHolder> {

private Context mContext;
private Done done;
private Realm mRealm;
private RealmResults<ListItems> mResults;
private int focusedItem = 0;
protected ToOtherFragmentCommunicator comm;


DoneAdapter(Context context, Realm realm, RealmResults<ListItems> results, Done done) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mRealm = realm;
    this.done = done;

    updateItems(results);
}

public void updateItems(RealmResults<ListItems> mResults) {
    this.mResults = mResults;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public ListItemsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.done_item, parent, false);
    comm = (ToOtherFragmentCommunicator) mContext;
    return new ListItemsViewHolder(v);
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ListItemsViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final ListItems items = mResults.get(position);

    holder.taskName.setText(items.getTaskName());

    try {
        if (items.getRenewCounter() == 1) {
            holder.renewCounter.setText(mContext.getString(R.string.show_days_till_renew, items.getRenewCounter(), mContext.getString(R.string.day)));
        } else {
            holder.renewCounter.setText(mContext.getString(R.string.show_days_till_renew, items.getRenewCounter(), mContext.getString(R.string.days)));
        }

        holder.renewCounter.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.colorAccent));
        if (items.getRenewCounter() <= 0) {
            mRealm.beginTransaction();

            //Problem 1.1.
            //send item back to todo list
            comm.itemToOtherFragment(items.getTaskName(), 0);
            // Produces "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling" if there is no Handler
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    mRealm.beginTransaction();
                    removeItem(position);
                    mRealm.commitTransaction();

                }
            };
            handler.post(r);
            mRealm.commitTransaction();
        }


    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    holder.itemView.setSelected(focusedItem == position);
    holder.getLayoutPosition();

}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (mResults != null ? mResults.size() : 0);
}

private void removeItem(int position) {
    mResults.get(position).removeFromRealm();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}


}
```

ListItems.java

```
public class ListItems extends RealmObject {

public ListItems(long addedTime, String taskName, String inputDate, String renewDate, int fragment) {
    this.addedTime = addedTime;
    this.taskName = taskName;
    this.inputDate = inputDate;
    this.renewDate = renewDate;
    this.fragment = fragment;
}

@PrimaryKey
private long addedTime;
private int fragment;
@Ignore
private long renewCounter;
private String taskName, inputDate, renewDate;
private boolean selected;

public ListItems() {
}

public long getAddedTime() {
    return addedTime;
}

public void setAddedTime(long addedTime) {
    this.addedTime = addedTime;
}

public int getFragment() {
    return fragment;
}

public void setFragment(int fragment) {
    this.fragment = fragment;
}

public String getTaskName() {
    return taskName;
}

public void setTaskName(String taskName) {
    this.taskName = taskName;
}

public String getInputDate() {
    return inputDate;
}

public void setInputDate(String inputDate) {
    this.inputDate = inputDate;
}

public String getRenewDate() {
    return renewDate;
}

public void setRenewDate(String renewDate) {
    this.renewDate = renewDate;
}

public boolean isSelected() {
    return selected;
}

public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
    this.selected = selected;
}

public long getRenewCounter() throws ParseException {
    TimeZone.getDefault();

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
    Date todayDate = new Date();
    Date exDate = dateFormat.parse(renewDate);

    this.renewCounter = daysBetween(todayDate, exDate);
    return renewCounter;

}

private static long daysBetween(Date startDate, Date endDate) {
    Calendar sDate = getDatePart(startDate);
    Calendar eDate = getDatePart(endDate);

    long daysBetween = 0;
    while (sDate.before(eDate)) {
        sDate.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        daysBetween++;
    }

    while (eDate.before(sDate)) {
        eDate.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        daysBetween--;
    }

    return daysBetween;
}

private static Calendar getDatePart(Date date) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();       // get calendar instance
    cal.setTime(date);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);            // set hour to midnight
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);                 // set minute in hour
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);                 // set second in minute
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);            // set millisecond in second

    return cal;                                  // return the date part
}

}
```

Here's a Screenshot on how the app looks like:
[DailyTaskRepeater](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvP3g.jpg)

That's it! It would mean the world to me if someone could help me with all that (especially Problem 1.1!).

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The current practice Realm supports is to add an index (e.g. timestamp) and to reverse sort your list for having the latest item at the top and achiving the rearranging effect you are seeking for.

Please consider taking a reference from [an adapter example](https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters) provided in the official repository.